# Sort a flat array so that multiple specified values occur before unmentioned values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort my 1d array so that two of the values are positioned in the first and second position.

```
$array = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Melon"];
```

I want to sort the array that first will be "Orange", then "Melon".

Desired result:

```
["Orange", "Melon", "Apple", "Banana"];
```

I looked at PHP's sort functions, but didn't find a sort function to do it.

Comment: Store `orange` and `Melon` in a tmp array, then prepend to a sorted one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution; using a custom function to move an element to the beginning of an array

```
function __unshift(&$array, $value){
    $key = array_search($value, $array);
    if($key) unset($array[$key]);
    array_unshift($array, $value);  
    return $array;
}

$a = array("Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Melon");
__unshift($a, "Melon");
__unshift($a, "Orange");
print_r($a);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Orange
    [1] => Melon
    [2] => Apple
    [3] => Banana
)
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/SCn6UD)

Or you may use the following to reorder an array using another array having reordered index

```
function __reorder(&$a, &$b){
    $c = array();
    foreach($b as $index){
        array_push($c, $a[$index]);
    }
    return $c;
}

// the original array
$a = array("Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Melon");
// an array with reordered index 
$b = array(1, 3, 0, 2);
$c = __reorder($a, $b);
print_r($c);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/pYDD9c)

Comment: i used it with a loop because i there is more then 2 first values, and could be one of them or more are not in the array. i used with a loop becuse i have more then 2 first values. :  
$first_values=array("Melon","Orange"); 
$first_values_reversed = array_reverse($first_values);
foreach($first_values_reversed as $first_value){
 if (in_array($first_value, $a)) {
  __unshift($a, $first_value);
 }
}

Comment: @batz Well done ;) I added another simple function to reorder the array so check the updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

What you looking for is [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), you can specify custom function to sort the array

example:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == "Orange") {
        return 1;
    }
    if ($b == "Orange") {
        return -1;
    }

    return strcmp($a, $b);// or any other sort you want
}

$arr = array("Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Melon");

usort($arr, "cmp");
```

Comment: So how in `usort` callback you will prepend `orange` as a first item?

Comment: The result is `"Apple" "Banana"  "Melon"  "Orange"`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that's longer than the others provided, but more flexible. You can easily expand or change the array of items that you want sorted first.

```
$array = array("Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Melon");
$sort_first = array("Orange", "Melon");

usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($sort_first) {
    $order_a = array_search( $a, $sort_first );
    $order_b = array_search( $b, $sort_first );

    if ($order_a === false && $order_b !== false) {
        return 1;
    } elseif ($order_b === false && $order_a !== false) {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($order_a === $order_b) {
        return $a <=> $b;
    } else {
        return $order_a <=> $order_b;
    }
});

// Result: $array = array("Orange", "Melon", "Apple", "Banana");
```

The function can also be easily altered if the items you're sorting aren't strings, such as arrays or objects. Here's an example that sorts an array of objects:

```
// Assuming $array is an array of users with a getName method
$sort_first = array("Sam", "Chris");

usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($sort_first) {
    $order_a = array_search( $a->getName(), $sort_first );
    $order_b = array_search( $b->getName(), $sort_first );

    if ($order_a === false && $order_b !== false) {
        return 1;
    } elseif ($order_b === false && $order_a !== false) {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($order_a === $order_b) {
        return $a->getName() <=> $b->getName();
    } else {
        return $order_a <=> $order_b;
    }
});

// $array will now have users Sam and Chris sorted first,
// and the rest in alphabetical order by name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$paths = array_merge(
    array_intersect(["Orange", "Melon"], ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Melon"]),
    array_diff(["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Melon"], ["Orange", "Melon"])
);
```

Comment: Please write what this code does so the OP can understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a lookup array where "Orange" has a value of `0` and "Melon" has a value of `1`. When an unmentioned values is encountered, give it a higher numeric value than all listed values. Sorting on these integers will make the task simple. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nAVDd))

```
$array = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Melon"];
$priority = array_flip(["Orange", "Melon"]);

usort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) => ($priority[$a] ?? PHP_INT_MAX) <=> ($priority[$b] ?? PHP_INT_MAX)
);

var_export($array);
```

---

Alternatively, because your input array's values are all unique, you could merely append unmentioned values to the end of your nominated order array. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0WXqh))

```
$array = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Melon"];
$priority = ["Orange", "Melon"];
var_export(
    array_merge($priority, array_diff($array, $priority))
);
```